# Magento 2 : Replace a custom JS component

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-2.1

We are working on a module that requires JS overwrite for file `Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default`.

- We are able to **overwrite the JS** using the steps provided in the [magento guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html).
- However this JS is already overwritten by **AvaTax module**.
- So instead of overwriting the default Magento JS we are trying to overwrite the Avatax JS using the same steps.
- We have added dependency in our module so that the Avatax module is loaded first.
- But this JS overwrite is successful only, if we overwrite the default Magento JS.

We don't want to make changes directly in the Avatax JS.

Is there any other way out?

Code used for overwrite:

```
 var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "ClassyLlama_AvaTax/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default" : "XYZ_Checkout/js/shipping-save-processor/default"
        }
    }
};
```

Code used for dependency:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="XYZ_Checkout" setup_version="2.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="ClassyLlama_AvaTax"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

We need to add extension attribute payload function as below:

```
                payload = {
                addressInformation: {
                    shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                    billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
                    shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                    shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                    extension_attributes: {
                        po_number: jQuery('[name="additional_po_number"]').val(),
                        spec_del_comment: jQuery('[name="additional_spec_del_comment"]').val(),
                        spec_del_comment_2: jQuery('[name="additional_spec_del_comment_2"]').val(),
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: Can you post code which you have used for dependency?

Comment: updated the question with details.

Comment: required js code?

Comment: updated the js code. we are adding extension attributes

Comment: and requirejs-config.js code?

Comment: Its added under title "Code used for overwrite:"

Comment: `ClassyLlama_AvaTax` is your module or that overridden module?

Comment: XYZ_Checkout is my module, ClassyLlama_AvaTax is the overridden module.

Comment: show your js file, XYZ_Checkout/js/shipping-save-processor/default

Comment: edited part is added under section "We need to add extension attribute payload function as below:"

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying the different possibilities, we think mapping works only for default JS files, and not for custom JS files.

To overwrite the JS we moved it to theme folder instead of overwriting it from Module.

The theme overwrite is working as expected.

Theme overwrite for `shipping-save-processor/default.js` is done as follows:

*app/design/frontend/xxx/yyy/ClassyLlama_AvaTax/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js*

Answer (score 0):

Your default.js file path

`XYZ/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/shipping-save-processor/default.js`

In **default.js** file,

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
        'ClassyLlama_AvaTax/js/view/checkout-validation-handler',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'
    ],
    function (
        $,
        quote,
        resourceUrlManager,
        storage,
        paymentService,
        methodConverter,
        errorProcessor,
        fullScreenLoader,
        selectBillingAddressAction,
        checkoutValidationHandler,
        alert
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            validateAddressContainerSelector: '#validate_address',
            saveShippingInformation: function () {
                var payload;

                if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
                    selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
                }

                payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                        billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
                        shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes: {
                            po_number: $('[name="additional_po_number"]').val(),
                            spec_del_comment: $('[name="additional_spec_del_comment"]').val(),
                            spec_del_comment_2: $('[name="additional_spec_del_comment_2"]').val(),
                        }
                    }
                };

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

                return storage.post(
                    resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
                    JSON.stringify(payload)
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                        paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                        // Begin Edit
                        try {
                            checkoutValidationHandler.validationResponseHandler(response);
                        } catch (e) {
                            $(this.validateAddressContainerSelector + " *").hide();
                        }
                        // End Edit
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        // Begin Edit - Native error message display is not obvious enough, so add to an alert box
                        var messageObject = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                        alert({
                            title: $.mage.__('Error'),
                            content: messageObject.message
                        });
                        //errorProcessor.process(response);
                        // End Edit
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Remove **var** folder,
clear cache.

Run command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I have written the similar code, but the problem is, that JS is already overwritten by a custom module, I am not able to overwrite that custom module JS.

Comment: If I overwrite mapping in require JS from custom module my code does not work where as if I overwrite it from default module, it works.

Comment: I have already mapped to your custom module

Comment: Please check your js file path, you havent call model folder so please check path also.

Comment: Also make sure that in app>etc>config.php your module name must be after ClassyLlama_AvaTax.  If not please change it according so module dependency work @DeepikaJaniyani

Comment: Yes our module name is after ClassyLlama_AvaTax